# How to query JSON Array in Postgres with SqlAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a SqlAlchemy model defined

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(255))
    contact_list = db.Column(JSONB)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

def add_user():
    user = User(nickname="Mike")
    user.contact_list = [{"name": "Sam", "phone": ["123456", "654321"]}, 
                         {"name": "John", "phone": ["159753"]},
                         {"name": "Joe", "phone": ["147889", "98741"]}]
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_user()
```

How can I retrieve the **name** from my *contact_list* using **phone**? For example, I have the **147889**, how can I retrieve **Joe**?

I have tried this

`User.query.filter(User.contact_list.contains({"phone": ["147889"]})).all()`

But, it returns me an empty list, `[]`

How can I do this?

Comment: If like to add to my answer, is there anything wrong with using a Python dictionary as a string, then using literal evaluation on the string?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just forgot that your JSON path should include the outermost array as well:

```
User.query.filter(User.contact_list.contains([{"phone": ["147889"]}])).all()
```

will return the user you are looking for. The original query would match, if your JSON contained an object with key "phone" etc. Note that this returns the `User` object in question, not the specific object/name from the JSON structure. If you want that, as seems to be the end goal, you could expand the array elements of each user, filter based on the resulting records, and select the name:

```
val = db.column('value', type_=JSONB)
db.session.query(val['name'].astext).\
    select_from(User,
                db.func.jsonb_array_elements(User.contact_list).alias()).\
    filter(val.contains({"phone": ["147889"]})).\
    all()
```

On the other hand the above query is not as index friendly as the first one can be, because it has to expand all the arrays before filtering, so it might be beneficial to first find the users that contain the phone in their contact list in a subquery or CTE, and then expand and filter.

Comment: Is it possible to return whole row. Ex: {"name": "Sam", "phone": ["123456", "654321"]}?

Comment: Sure, `query(val)`.

Comment: Hmm, I have checked, and for me, all items are returned, not only found phones, but the whole collection...

Comment: Ah, you meant like that. Note that `filter(val.contains({"phone": ["147889"]}))` simply checks if the number is contained in the row, but it does not remove other numbers, when returning the row as a result. For that you need an additional step, or a different kind of query altogether.

Comment: What would the syntax be with Core (not ORM)?

Comment: any solution to only retrieve @llja specific rows not all

Comment: If by specific you mean for example 1 row, you can use `one()`, `one_or_none()`, or `first()` in case you want to fetch a model object. If you want to limit the number of rows, use `limit()`.