# Sqlalchemy filter nested jsonb within arrays

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I have a Postgres JSONB field, with some nested arrays and other objects.

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB


class Family(db.Model):
   meta = db.Column(JSONB)


joes = Family(meta=[
    {
        "name": "Joe",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Jane"
            },
            {
                "name": "Kate"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Lisa",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Mary"
            },
            {
                "name": "David"
            }
        ]
    },
])
```

Is there a way to query all the kids with a certain substring in their names?

If I want to query for `'a'` it should get me `Mary, David, Kate, Jane`.

I was thinking, maybe something like

```py
Family.query.filter(
    Family.meta.contains([{"children": [{"name": func.contains("a")}]}])
)
```

Comment: There is, for example adapting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52190109/how-to-query-json-array-in-postgres-with-sqlalchemy), but it helps in providing answers if you provide the models, what you've tried etc. to work with.

Comment: Thanks! I looked at it, but I'm not sure how can it be adapted for multiple nested array objects. I've added a dummy model, but I don't think that it depends on the model's structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to unnest the array or arrays using [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), and then filter:

```
meta_value = literal_column('meta.value', type_=JSONB)
children_value = literal_column('children.value', type_=JSONB)

Family.query.\
    with_entities(children_value['name'].astext).\
    select_from(
        Family,
        func.jsonb_array_elements(Family.meta).alias('meta'),
        func.jsonb_array_elements(
            meta_value['children']).alias('children')).\
    filter(children_value['name'].astext.contains('a'))
```

Note the use of [`literal_column()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column) to reference the values of the set returning function [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

Another option is to use `jsonb_path_query()` (introduced in version 12):

```
name = column('name', type_=JSONB)
Family.query.\
    with_entities(name.astext).\
    select_from(
        func.jsonb_path_query(
            Family.meta,
            '$[*].children[*].name').alias('name')).\
    filter(name.astext.contains('a')).\
    all()
```