# Is it possible to search a JSONB List for a value using "LIKE" and SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

For example, if I have a JSONB column, and it is stored as:

```
["oranges","apples","bananas"]
```

How can I check using a LIKE type search if the substring "app" is in the list?

Ideally I would like be able to do something like:

```
Basket['fruits'].contains_like('%app%')
```

Is this possible with sqlalchemy?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54669900/sqlalchemy-filter-nested-jsonb-within-arrays, it should be fairly straightforward to adapt to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Using inspiration from the pure PostgreSQL answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50111177/5015356), you can create the following condition:

```py
from sqlalchemy import exists, func, literal_column

exists().select_from(
  func.jsonb_array_elements_text(Basket['fruits']).alias('fruit')
).where(literal_column('fruit').like('%app%'))
```

The answer raises the issue of performance and potentially adding an index in special cases (when you're only interested in strings starting with a certain value). Have a look if that applies to you and if you experience performance issues

Comment: See Postgres Documentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-json.html then section 8.14.3. jsonb Containment and Existence

Comment: @Belayer I read the documentation you posted, but I don't understand why you included it. This is very useful for full string matches, but not so much for the partial string matches the original question is about